# Foldable Attribute Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0

How to design Foldable Layout for Android Q compatible devices.

During this transition, how app will receive a configuration change for the new layout?

Will Multi Resume collide of multiple activities?

Answer (score 2):

Android Gives support for multiple windows from Android 8.0 (API level 26).
You can manage multiple screens at the same time in the application. For that, you need to follow multiwindow lifecycle and handle configurations.

Check below link for reference.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html#lifecycle

Below are some methods which may help you :

`ActivityOptions` provides two new methods to support multiple displays:

`setLaunchDisplayId()` Specifies which display the activity should be shown on when it is launched.
`getLaunchDisplayId()` Returns the activity's current launch display.

Apart from this,

Set this attribute in your manifest's  or  element to enable or disable multi-window display:

```
android:resizeableActivity=["true" | "false"]
```